# AES SYmmetric Keys

Tags: c#, aes

I am following this link https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-Word-Excel-PDF-Text-or-Image-Files-using-C-and-VBNet-in-ASPNet.aspx and there is we can encrypt a file with a Encryption key and can decrypt it using that same key

is there any way I can use two key for encryption one for user level and other one will be master key.

my requirement is: user will encrypt the file with a key and if they forget the key than there should be a master key to decrypt.

Comment: that will be tricky. since a blob encrypted with key A wont be able decrypted with key B unless you found two different key that behave the same way (i doubt it exists, if it does, the encryption algorithm will be deemed as insecure). following boomelding, yes, you can put the user key and encrypt that using the master key. but the idea putting the key right beside the encrypted blob still escapes me as you will need to design your binary in someway.

Comment: thank for the comment, can I use public key and private key for this case

Comment: unfortunately no, data encrypted with private key can only be decrypted using public key and vice versa..

Comment: Do you provide user with his key, or user generates this key in completely independent way?